# Strip Unwanted Characters from a String in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlplus

```
    Public Function StripUnwanted(ByVal unwanted_strIn) As String

On Error GoTo Err_StripUnwanted

Dim lngCount As Long

If Not IsNull(unwanted_strIn) Then

    For lngCount = 1 To Len(unwanted_strIn)

        If IsNumeric(Mid$(unwanted_strIn, lngCount, 1)) Then
        strOut = strOut & Mid$(unwanted_strIn, lngCount, 1)
        End If

    Next lngCount

End If

StripUnwanted = strOut

Exit_StripUnwanted:
     Exit Function

Err_StripUnwanted:
     MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description
     Resume Exit_StripUnwanted
```

I have been given the above code which works in VB linked into access, I am trying to convert this code into SQLPlus but I am unsure how to even go about it. I've tried to google and not getting very far any help or direction would be great.

Comment: SQLPlus has a regexreplace, any reason why you can't use this?  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [`translate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions216.htm#SQLRF06145):

**If you're just working with strings passed in that don't come from a table:**

```
declare
  v_val varchar2(20);
begin
  v_val := translate('abcdef', '1abc', '1');
  dbms_output.put_line(v_val);
end;
/

def
```

**If you're working with strings that come from a table:**

```
select translate('abcdef', '1abc', '1')
from   dual;

TRANSLATE('ABCDEF','1ABC','1')
------------------------------
def
```